# Is it possible to purposely make a program thrash?

Tags: operating-system

I know what thrashing is but after taking my operating systems course at university, I was wondering if it is possible to purposely get a program thrashing or are the operating systems of today "too smart" to fall for any tricks?

Can I make my program spend more time loading pages than executing code in any way?

Answer (score 1):

If you deliberately wanted a process to thrash, you could allocate as many pages as possible to the process, then randomly write to different pages.

This only works if you can allocate enough memory that is greater than the physical memory available on the system.